# How to describe a husky, low, sinister voice?

Tags: characters, description, voice

**Hello!** While I was writing for my fantasy novel, I was stuck on how to describe a very scratchy and low, but malicious voice for a grim reaper kind of like ghost in my story. The voice I'm trying to describe resembles Phantomon from the Digimon series... Especially in the game; Rumble Arena 2. It's just so intimidating and horrifying, I'm having a hard time with describing it, anyone has any idea? I'll be grateful!

Comment: This is leaning towards a what-to-write question. However, I would recommend the ideas of attributing it to a certain thing, eg using words that have connotations of violence or death or aggression, or even deception.

Comment: How about "(s)he said, in a husky, low, sinister voice"?  Why overcomplicate things? :)

Comment: You are asking What to Write. And I agree with GordonM. You can always fix the description on your rewrite.

Answer (score 1):

You might not need to describe the voice at all. If the character is a grim-reaper sort, I'd assume it had a low scary voice. That's pretty much the default voice for that kind of creature, isn't it?

If you want to make clear that it's a scary voice, then have other characters react to it with fear.

Answer (score 0):

I would dare propose you could either link it with something your target audience can understand or relate, or you could very specifically describe it. Theres a whole list of words used to describe someone's voice [here](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus-category/british/words-used-to-describe-someone-s-voice).

Maybe something like this is what you're looking for?:

> A toneless guttural voice was heard. As gravelly and penetrating as it was gruff.

Comment: Unless you are writing a dictionary,this isn't a sentence anybody is looking for. Way too many specific adjectives. I mean merely listing a set of attributes is actually neither interesting to read, nor gets the point across.  I read that sentence and besides scratching my head to remember what some of those words mean, they didn't paint an image of this voice in my head, actually describing something succesfully goes further than adding an adjective or two.